# Multi level MongoDB object querying by key

Tags: mongodb

If you only know the key name (say "nickname"), but not the exact path to that key in the object.

e.g. nickname may be at the first level like:

```
{"nickname":"Howie"}
```

or at the second level:

```
{"user":{"nickname":"Howie"}}
```

Is it possible to query for nickname equal "`Howie`" that would return both documents?

Comment: Hope this gets answered, all I can see is `.find({nickname:"Howie"})` only returns the top level.

Comment: Only if you know all the possible paths and combine them with an `$or`.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no wild card that allows you to search for a field at any level in the db. If the position is not relevant and you can modify the document structure you have 2 choices here. You can store your document as

```
{ fieldname:"nickname", value : "Howie" }
{ fieldname:"user/nickname", value: "Howie" }
```

You can then query using

```
db.so.find({fieldname:/nickname/, value:"Howie"})
```

Alternatively you can store as

```
db.so.insert({value:"Howie", fieldpath:["nickname"]})
db.so.insert({value:"Howie", fieldpath:["user", "nickname"]})
```

The advantage with the second approach is that you can now index {fieldpath:1, value:1} and a query on it such as

```
db.so.find({fieldpath:"nickname", value:"Howie"})
```

will be an indexed query.

Comment: Thanks Sridhar, this is really helpful! It seems in this way you can translate any multilevel object into a one level object by using field path or namespacing the key. I just wonder if it is a good/effective solution or just an ad hoc solution that should be used only when particularly needed, since it is so different from the normal suggested pattern.